# How to copy link to highlight using chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the Chrome browser, we can select a text, then the context menu (right click) there is an option [Copy link to highlight](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10256233?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#:%7E:text=Copy%20link%20to%20highlight)

It is possible and how to copy link or apply/remove that specific highlight on a selection range using [chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/) at chrome extensions.

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
// chrome.highlight.add(range);
// chrome.highight.remove();
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this, and how? I am trying to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to provide a workaround: copy [this file](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/link-to-text-fragment/blob/main/fragment-generation-utils.js)(or [this one](https://github.com/eduOS/temptemp/blob/master/fragment-generation-utils.js) I have tested) and place it in your extension as one of your content scripts or background scripts, and you just use that by passing a selection to get the results as follows:

```
  getLinkToSelected(selection) {
    const result = generateFragment(selection);
    let url = `${location.origin}${location.pathname}${location.search}`;
    if (result.status === 0) {
      const fragment = result.fragment;
      const prefix = fragment.prefix ?
        `${encodeURIComponent(fragment.prefix)}-,` :
        '';
      const suffix = fragment.suffix ?
        `,-${encodeURIComponent(fragment.suffix)}` :
        '';
      const textStart = encodeURIComponent(fragment.textStart);
      const textEnd = fragment.textEnd ?
        `,${encodeURIComponent(fragment.textEnd)}` :
        '';
      
      console.log(`prefix: ${prefix}\ntextstart: ${textStart}\ntextend: ${textEnd}\nsuffix: ${suffix}`)
      url = `${url}#:~:text=${prefix}${textStart}${textEnd}${suffix}`;
      console.log(`fragment url: ${url}`)
      return url;
    } else {
      return `Could not create URL ${result.status}`;
    }
```

}

You can use it like this:

```
var userSelection = window.getSelection();
var derective_url = this.getLinkToSelected(userSelection)
```

I think it would be easy to make it an API. When I can do it myself, I will update this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with the Chrome API.
But you can compose the link yourself.

When you look at the structure of the link-to-highlight URL.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806679/how-to-copy-link-to-highlight-using-chrome-api#:~:text=How%20to%20copy%20link%20to%20highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806679/how-to-copy-link-to-highlight-using-chrome-api#:%7E:text=How%20to%20copy%20link%20to%20highlight)

It consist of three parts:

1. the original URL
2. the `#:~:text=` parameter
3. and the actual URL encoded text selection

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();
const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
const linkToHighlight = location.href + "#:~:text=" + encodeURIComponent(range.toString())
```

Comment: This is not correct. It is more clever than that (your solution doesn't handle situations when there are multiple target highlights on the same page)